# ASP.NET Web Administration tool; asp.net connection string

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have ASP.NET webapplication on my local machine and SQL Server database on a server. I ran aspnet_regsql.exe on the server. After that I created admin role from ASP.NET administration tool. Also created one user with admin privileges. Under the security section in sql server, provided that user db_owner access. Now when I m trying to run my application, I m getting the below error,

```
Server Error in '/UBCAT' Application.

Login failed for user 'admin'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'admin'.

Source Error: 


Line 36: 
Line 37:         context.Logins.AddObject(login);
Line 38:         context.SaveChanges();
Line 39:     }
Line 40:
```

//Connection String:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="UBCATSqlAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"
    timeout="60" />
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="60" />
<membership defaultProvider="UBCATSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="60">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UBCATSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="UBCATDB" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="UBCAT" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UBCATSqlRoleProvider" cookieTimeout="60">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="UBCATDB" applicationName="UBCAT" name="UBCATSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using [legacy Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx). Here is the new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) *which is backward compatible with legacy Membership Provider*.

If you want the latest Membership Provider, you want to look at [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) *which is not backward compatible with legacy Membership Provider*.

> Login failed for user 'admin'.

According to the error message, login credential for the SQL Server is not correct.